# CsvHelper PrepareHeaderForMatch causing CS1546 exception when compiling on Azure

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, csvhelper

I've upgraded to the latest CsvHelper library v25, the project is built using C# language v7.3 with .NET v4.7.2. Building and testing locally works ok but when I trigger the pipeline and deploy the solution to Azure App service, I'm getting a the following compiler exception:

> Property, indexer, or event 'PrepareHeaderForMatchArgs.Header' is not
> supported by the language; try directly calling accessor methods
> 'PrepareHeaderForMatchArgs.get_Header()' or
> 'PrepareHeaderForMatchArgs.set_Header(?)'

The message refers to Compiler Error CS1546 found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1546):

This is the snippet of the CsvHelper implementation:

```
 var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            {
               PrepareHeaderForMatch = args => args.Header.ToLowerInvariant()
            };

  using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(file.InputStream))
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(r, config))
            {
                csv.Context.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<Decimal>(new DecimalConverter());
                csv.Context.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<DateTime>(new DateConverter());
                csv.Context.RegisterClassMap(mapper);
                data = csv.GetRecords<BankDetailFields>().ToList();
            }
```

If I remove

> PrepareHeaderForMatch = args => args.Header.ToLowerInvariant()

it then deploys correctly. I've checked and made sure its using C# v7.3 on deployment, I haven't tried other c# language version yet.

Has anyone come across a similar issue with CS1546, any other approach to the PrepareHeaderForMatch implementation.

Cheers.

Comment: I haven't deployed it in Azure, but just wanted to say thanks for the code snippet on how to use PrepareHeaderForMatch - it worked for me locally